# Deleting a users account data and redirect to login screen

Tags: php, dns, web-hosting

I am adding a 'Delete my account' function to an application which calls the code:

```
if ($cmd == "DeleteAccountConfirm")  {
    DeleteUsersAccount();
    header("Location: index.php?cmd=logout&msg=Account deleted successfully");      
}
```

The DeleteUsersAccount() function checks the users id and then calls DELETES for all records of that player from the appropriate tables, but the issue seems to be the logout function as follows:

```
if ($cmd == "logout" )  { 
        unset($_SESSION['user']);  
        unset($_SESSION['login_time']);  
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);  
        session_unset(); 
        session_destroy();  
        if ($msg == "") { $msg = "logged out successfully"; }
        header("Location: index.php?cmd=View&menu=".$selected_menu."&msg=".$msg); 
}
```

My question is - is this a valid/secure way to wipe a users account and redirect them to the login screen? Anything else I need to take into account?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not working? Looks reasonable...

Comment: Thanks for checking - during development of this code I managed to take out all my domains on my shared webhost (unresponsive - QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38110), so I just wanted to make sure the basic idea is correct and there was nothing in the sessions clearing that I missed. I did have a redirect loop at one stage which probably didn't help (got a too many connections error), but I am surprised it affected all my domains.

Comment: You could probably skip all the 'unset' and 'destroy' by simply having your login page init everything every time. Also from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php it looks like the session cookie is still on the client machine until you remove it.